# React Router onEnter with Redux authentication

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use the onEnter of Router from `react-router-dom` to validate if a user is authenticate. I'm keeping the authentication in the login reducer.

Initial State:

```
const initialState = {
    logged: false,
    userName: null
}
```

In my App.js I have my Router

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';

function App() {
  const login = useSelector((state) => state.login);

  const requireAuth = (nextState, replace, next) => {
      console.log(login)
    if(!login.logged) {
      replace({
        pathname: "/login",
        state: {nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname}
      });
    }
    next();
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} onEnter={requireAuth} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

It is not redirecting to the `/login`. Actually, it is not calling the `requireAuth` function because the browser does not show the log that I have inside the function. What am I missing in the Router settings?
By the way, is it an appropriate way to check if a user is authenticate before navigating to a page?

Thanks

Updated code using `PrivateRoute`. Error: `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded.`

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';

function App() {
  
  const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
    const login = useSelector((state) => state.login);
      console.log(login);
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={({ location }) =>
          login.logged ? (
            children
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/login",
                state: { from: location }
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute path="/">
          <Home />
        </PrivateRoute>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, the best approach is what you can see in [react-router example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) page.

you better define a route to your private pages like this:

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  const login = useSelector((state) => state.login);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        login ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/public">
       <PublicPage />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/login">
       <LoginPage />
    </Route>
    <PrivateRoute path="/protected">
       <ProtectedPage />
    </PrivateRoute>
</Switch>
```

**update:**

you updated your post so, for those who may make this mistake:

in the updated code we have this switch structure:

```
<Switch>
    <PrivateRoute path="/">
      <Home />
    </PrivateRoute>
    <Route path="/login">
      <Login />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

when we redirect user to `/login` page. it matches the first route (`/`) too. so `Switch` select the first `PrivateRoute` to render and it makes an infinite loop.

there is two ways to tackle the problem:

**first:** put longer and more specific routes first within `Switch` hierarchy. for example in your code you could do this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/login">
      <Login />
    </Route>
    <PrivateRoute path="/">
      <Home />
    </PrivateRoute>
</Switch>
```

**second:** use `exact` in more generic routes that comes first:

```
<Switch>
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/">
      <Home />
    </PrivateRoute>
    <Route path="/login">
      <Login />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: From you example, when I try to access ```localhost:3000/login``` it returns ```Error: Maximum update depth exceeded``` because it calls the ```PrivateRoute``` method multiple times

Comment: try `<PrivateRoute exact path="/">`. (add exact keyword)

Comment: remember when your url is `/login` it matches both path you defined. (`/` and `/login`) and it chooses the first one, because of the Switch component

Comment: Thanks! Every path that I add, will match the first ```/```? In this case, should I move the ```/``` to the end of the ```Switch```?

Comment: yes, or as I updated my answer, you can use `exact` property on your root `/` route.